# Get better/more details stats from goo.gl URL shorterner service?

Tags: url, statistics, url-shortener, google-url-shortener, goo.gl

By default the goo.gl URL shorterner service just offers very coarse statistics for shortened links, `last two hours`, `last day`, `last week` and `last month` and `all time`. If you want to look at the statistics for yesterday you have to look at `last week` and if you want to look at the stats for the previous month you have to look at `all time`.

Is there a way to have, e.g., month view and then scroll back month by month? Some third party solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution as below about your question. May be that can help you

> If you have already created a shortened goo.gl url just type .info at
>   the end (e.g. goo.gl/url.info)